# Exclude fastcgi from running php on an specific folder

Tags: php, nginx, security

Users can upload files on my webserver to a specific directory.  In order to be more secure I want to exclude `php-fastcgi` from parsing PHP scripts in that specific directory.

```
directory = /server/files/

location ~ \.php$ {
   try_files $uri =404;
   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_nam$
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are [many ways to do this](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/), but just *not loading PHP files in a particular folder* is [*not enough*](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php). Someone could upload a file with a .jpg extension that actually contains PHP code and then execute it.

So we'll do *two* things:

1. First, only execute files if they have a .php extension. Add into your PHP `location`:

   ```
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   ```

   Here, any file that doesn't end in `.php` will instead be routed to `index.php` of your application, with the filename set in $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']. What happens then depends on how your application handles this. It may deliver a 404, or serve your home page, for instance.
2. Don't execute PHP files in a particular folder at all (your original question):

   ```
   location /uploads {
       location ~ \.php$ {return 403;}
   }
   ```

   Hopefully what this does is obvious.